# Sitecore Exception Handling Policy (Similar to Entlib)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've been searching for haven't found single article on whether sitecore supports policy based (like Entlib) exception handling and logging.

Could someone please help me on right direction, whether above is possible using latest sitecore?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore itself doesn't have a policy based exception handling mechanism in the same sense as Entlib. That said there is nothing stopping you introducing Entlib policy based exception handling into your Sitecore website as it is still just a regular ASP.NET web application. You can make calls to ExceptionPolicy.HandleException where ever you would normally trap and respond to thrown exceptions in your code.

To get started take a look at the John West post [Error Management with the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/09/Error-Management-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) and also give some consideration to adding an Application level error handler that applies the Entlib policy that you've setup.

Comment: Thanks Kevin very helpful, I'm still confused with the blog post. Given sitecore handles exception out of box why we need to handle page level, application level etc. Isn't try catch on controller, BLL and DLL & Application_Error() good enough to trap all exceptions? Sitecore is confusing, thought would be easy to implement.